# Access Objects as Dictionary

Tags: c#

I use a 3rd party library and am un able to get the object arrays' content

```
IDictionary dic=SomeFunc(); // this function returns an IDictionary
```

and I use DictionaryEntry to get its content

```
foreach(DictionaryEntry de in dic)
{
   //each of de.Value is implemented as a KeyValuePair<object,object>
   //I have not yet learned how to read each de.Value's key and value pair
}
```

Could you offer me a hint to get the strings inside de.Value which is a dictionary of object to object ?

EDIT
Each value of de.Values is a key value pair of type "object" to "object". It reports error when I cast it to string

```
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in dic)
{
   foreach(KeyValuePair<string,string> k in (Dictionary<string,string>)de.Values)
   {
      //error: instance is null
   }
}
```

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if you got info you want

Answer (score 0):

make use of is keywork

```
if(de.value is typeof(Dictionary))
//than do code
```

not sure but this will work

Answer (score 0):

To access only the values, have this:

```
foreach (object value in dic.Values)
{
    MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
}
```

If you mean each value is Dictionary by its own right then you can have nested loop:

```
foreach (object value in dic.Values)
{
    Dictionary<object, object> nestedDic = (Dictionary<object, object>)value;
    foreach (object nestedValue in nestedDic.Values)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(nestedValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, The outer forloop reports an error as object doesn't have a public getEnumerator method,